# ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=vbp -missingModuleFor: vbp. I have imported the required modules

Tags: highcharts, angular-material, angular-highcharts

I'm trying to use volume-by-price of highchart in my angular project. I have checked if the current version of highcharts installed supports the vbp and it does support. I have installed the highcharts angular and highcharts and imported as mentioned in the documentation. The steps i have followed is from this link(https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular#installing).Since I'm using it in searching.components.ts, I have used it in that component and also imported the other modules required import 'highcharts/indicators/indicators'; import 'highcharts/indicators/volume-by-price'; and checked in my indicators whether volume-by-price.ts is present. It is included in the path provided and vbp is already present and it automatically came when i was typing the 'type' in 'series'. and it shows the error:  core.mjs:7473 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=vbp](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=vbp) - missingModuleFor: vbp at Object.<anonymous> (highstock.js:8:138) at C (highstock.js:8:2591) at r (highstock.js:8:61) at k.initSeries (highstock.js:8:195150) at highstock.js:8:210174 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at k.firstRender (highstock.js:8:210152) at k.<anonymous> (highstock.js:8:195068) at C (highstock.js:8:2591) at k.init (highstock.js:8:194486) . My complete code in searching.component.ts (have included these lines at the top: import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'; import 'highcharts/indicators/indicators'; import 'highcharts/indicators/volume-by-price';). I have used this in my typescript(searching.component.ts):

```
    series: [{
    type: 'candlestick',
    name: 'CAST',
    id: 'cast',
    zIndex: 2,
    data: ohlc
    }, 
    {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    id: 'volume',
    data: volume,
    yAxis: 1,
    threshold: null ,
    pointRange: 1,
    pointWidth: 5
    },{
    type :'vbp',
    linkedTo: 'cast',
    params: {
    volumeSeriesID: 'volume'
    },
    dataLabels:
    {
    enabled: false
    }
    }]
```

and the below code is present in a function when user clicks on charts, the function getDetails() is called and getDetails() has this code:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('containerChart',
{ 
rangeSelector: { selected: 1 }, 
title: { text: 'SMA' }, 
subtitle: { text: 'With SMA and Volume by Price technical indicators' }, 
xAxis: { type:'datetime' }, 
yAxis: [{ startOnTick: false, endOnTick: false,
   labels: {
        align: 'right',
        format: '{value:.2f}',
        x: -3
    },
    title: {
        text: 'OHLC'
    },
   height: '60%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    resize: {
        enabled: true
    },
    tickPositions: (() => {
      const ohlcValues = ohlc.map(point => [point[2], point[3]]).flat(); // Assuming point[2] is high and point[3] is low for each point
      const min = Math.min(...ohlcValues);
      const max = Math.max(...ohlcValues);
      let positions = [];
      let interval = (max - min) / 5; // Adjust the number of ticks by changing the divisor
  
      for (let i = min; i <= max; i += interval) {
          positions.push(parseFloat(i.toFixed(2))); // Adding toFixed to handle floating-point precision
      }
  
      console.log("Min:", min, "Max:", max, "Tick positions:", positions);
      return positions;
    })(),
}, {
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3,
        formatter: function() {
          return (+(this.value) / 1e6) + 'M'; }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Volume'
    },
    tickPositions: [0, 50e6, 100e6, 150e6],
    top: '65%',
    height: '35%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
}],
tooltip: {
    split: true
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false, 
    }
},
column: {
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    pointWidth: 3, 
}, },
series: [{
    type: 'candlestick',
    name: 'CAST',
    id: 'cast',
    zIndex: 2,
    data: ohlc
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    id: 'volume',
    data: volume,
    yAxis: 1,  
    threshold: null ,
    pointRange: 1,
    pointWidth: 5
},{
  type :'vbp',
  linkedTo: 'cast',
  params: {
    volumeSeriesID: 'volume'
  },
  dataLabels:
  {
    enabled: false
  }
}
  ] });
```

Could you please let me know if I have to include any other modules or can I implement vbp in any other way?

Comment: Hi @Usha, Which Highcharts and highcharts-anguler versions do you use? Also, are you sure that you imported and initialized the `indicators` and `volume-by-price` modules as described in the docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#to-load-a-module ? Working example in pure JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qcgtj7x3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly import and initialize Highstock, indicators and volume-by-price modules.

For example:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import indicators from 'highcharts/indicators/indicators';
import volumeByPrice from 'highcharts/indicators/volume-by-price';

indicators(Highcharts);
volumeByPrice(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-cmca2i

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#to-load-a-module

Comment: When I try to import it this way, it gives me an error: [vite] Internal server error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Core/Chart/Chart.js')

Comment: Hi @Usha, It works fine in the example that I provided, so please check your dependencies and eventually reproduce the issue in the live example. Legend should be disabled by default if you are using Highstock, in another case, just disable it by: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled